# Не работает tasklist на удаленной машине

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Подскажите пожалуйста, что за дела, где я неправильно делаю? Мне нужно получить процессы на удаленной машине. Если не использовать фильтр /FI, то я получаю, но стоит задать фильтр, как ничего не выводит.

```
using (Process dotnetProc = new Process())
            {
                dotnetProc.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                dotnetProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "tasklist /s 192.168.0.0 /u login /p pass /FI \"IMAGENAME eq 1cv7s.exe\"";
                dotnetProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                dotnetProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                dotnetProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                dotnetProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                dotnetProc.Start();
                Console.WriteLine(dotnetProc.StartInfo.Arguments);
                strings = "";
                do
                {
                    strings= dotnetProc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                }
                while (!dotnetProc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream);
                dotnetProc.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Если в powershell задать эту команду, то она будет выполнена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот через код ничего не выходит. В строку strings попросту ничего не записывается. Я и while и do while пробовал.И powershell на cmd менял. Через cmd кстати есть вывод, но я там получаю какие то огромные данные странных строк.

Потом... Я обрезал аргумент до

```
tasklist /s 192.168.0.0 /u login /p password
```

и успешно получал вывод всех процессов. А с фильтром, почему-то не работает.  Я не так пишу аргумент, получается?

Comment: `strings += …`?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению нет. Я еще забыл написать, что он не заходит в цикл while, а если это do while, он просто выходит из него, после первого прохождения и имеем пустую строку

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C ?

Comment: Тут то, что вам нужно, и без костылей: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17935/Manage-Processes-on-Remote-Machine

Answer (score 0):

Был неверно передан аргумент.
Нужно было

```
$@"tasklist /s 192.168.0.1 /u login /p password /FI " + '\'' + "IMAGENAME eq 1cv7s.exe" + '\''
```